# No viable overloaded

Tags: c++, xcode, class, properties

I have 2 classes **CVKinectWrapper.cpp** and **main.cpp**. In the CVKinectWrapper, in the `bool CVKinectWrapper::update(){ ...` i have a variable `XnSkeletonJointPosition righthand;` I would like to access this variable in the **main.cpp** class. therefor i have created a

```
`void CVKinectWrapper::getRightHand(XnSkeletonJointPosition *righthand){
  //*righthand = righthand;

  righthand->copyTo(*righthand);
}`
```

The direct assignment doesn't work, i get this error = '**No match for 'operator=' in*righthand=righthand**'.
The copyTo doesnt work because the datatype of righthand hasn't got this method.

For extra info :

This is how i access the wrapper in the main class = `CVKinectWrapper *wrapper = CVKinectWrapper::getInstance();`

```
 wrapper->getRightHand(XnSkeletonJointPosition *righthand)
```

My question now is how can i access the righthand variable from the CVKinectWrapper in the main class.

This is probably a very basic question but i'm rather new to c++.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the question tagged `objective-c` (I have removed hat tag)? Also consider adding the complete error message to questions about compiler/linker errors, you have removed important information (like the types of the objects at both sides of the `=`). Finally when adding code, make sure that the code that you are adding is the code in your program. I quite doubt that the call in `main` is literally `wrapper->getRightHand(XnSkeletonJointPosition *righthand)`

Comment: I updated the error message. And yes it is really that call in the main.

Comment: You have still cut away from the error message the types of the arguments. And if that is really the call in `main`, then you have another problem as you are trying to pass `XnSkeletonJointPosition *righthand` as argument to the function, which makes no sense at all (that *looks* like the multiplication of a type times a probably undefined identifier... did you intend to create a new variable in place? you cannot. Consider returning by value rather than taking a pointer as argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking about compiler errors, it is usually a good idea to provide the exact error message, which in this case it probably states what the types of the two arguments are. At any rate, I think I can guess what the problems are.

You mention that you have a variable named `righthand`, which I assume is actually a *member* of the class, and you want to copy the value to a different variable passed to the function `getRightHand`. Now the problem is that the argument of the function has the same name as the member, and it is *shadowing* it. Inside `getRightHand`, the identifier `righthand` refers to the argument, not to the member. You can solve this by either changing the name of the argument or qualifying the access to the member: `*righthand = this->righthand;`

As of the particular error message, the operation `*righthand = righthand;` literally means assign the value of the pointer `righthand` (argument to the function) to the object that it points, which does not make much sense. From a design point of view, the function as it is is quite un-idiomatic in C++, and should probably be replaced by:

```
const XnSkeletonJointPosition& CVKinectWrapper::getRightHand() const {
  return righthand;
}
```

And the caller would do:

```
XnSkeletonJointPosition res = wrapper.getRightHand();
```

Comment: when i use your proposed method i get this error: Out-of-line definition of 'getRightHand' does not match any declaration in 'CVKinectWrapper'. Btw i also have an .h file . Should there be some kind of declaration in that h file ?

Comment: @Ojtwist: The declaration of the members in the class and the definition of those members must match. I really believe that you need to start with a good introductory book on C++, SO is a place for specific questions, but you need a full tutorial to take you through the basics...

Comment: yes it does seem to be a good idea to get a tutorial to get me through the basics. Though i would like a solution if possible. So my question is how would i do this declaration in the h file of the method you proposed ?

Comment: @Ojtwist `const XnSkeletonJointPosition& getRightHand() const` inside the class declaration